# Firefox issue - inline DIV with text

Tags: css

I can't figure out a way to make this work in Firefox and I'm hoping you can give me some suggestions. I need all the text inside the DIV class .inline-text to appear besides the LABEL and wrap based on the available width. It works fine in IE but Firefox doesn't like it and pushes it the entire block onto a new line. It would work fine if I set the .inline-text to have a fixed width, but unfortunately for my project I can't do that so I need a way for this to be "liquid" and still appear inline.

My CSS:

```
#container {
width:530px;
}
label {
font-weight:bold;
text-align:right;
width:130px;
margin-right:20px;
float:left;
display:inline;
}
.inline-text {
float:left;
display:inline;
}
```

My HTML

```
<div id="container">
<label>A label</label>
<div class="inline-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Aenean   commodo ligula eget dolor.  Aenean massa.  Cum sociis natoque penatibus   et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you want:

```
.inline-text {
  margin-left: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ro unfortunately that pushes the inline-text block one line down compared to the label, since it cannot fit right beside it :(

Comment: Oops, I forgot you need to drop the float left, too.

Comment: I tried that and it worked fine, so I have now solved 50% of my issues. Basically in my setup there are several items with float left. If we know the width of what's before the .inline-text (i.e. the Label), then I am ok using your method by setting the margin-left. However if I have more than one item in the same row all with float left (i.e. a label and an input field), then I would not be able to set the margin-left, because it's an unknown value. If you have any suggestions on how to tackle that it would be brilliant! :)

Comment: In your solution, in order to avoid the text wrapping around the Label it is necessary to add overflow:hidden; to the inline-text class.

Answer (score 0):

delete `float:left;` from `.inline-text` and the `width:130px;` from `label`

example: http://jsbin.com/usozi3

Comment: Hi Sot thanks for giving it a shot but the example is still not working. Removing the width of the label is not an option for me (this sample code is part of a much larger page), but also in your example the text is wrapping around the label, instead of sitting in a block beside the label.

Comment: @ale well you can use for .inline-text the display:table but it will not work for ie:7 and down. An other option is to set a fixed height for the label. The third solution to use javascript